# Probability Strategy

Tags: probability-distributions

A charity fund-raiser has found that active soliciting gains \$5 contributions with probability .7 and passive soliciting gains \$10 contributions with probability .4. No other contributions are made. What strategy should be pursued to gain the maximum contributions?

I'm fairly sure that the strategy needs to be a mixture of active and passive soliciting, but I do not know how to calculate the proportion for each.

Comment: Do you have any restrictions? Or is that all? If you have other details please name them.

Answer (score 2):

Expected value of active soliciting $\$5\cdot0.7=\$3.5$, and expected value of passive solciting $\$10\cdot0.4=\$4$. So, if we take this as criterion, then passive soliciting has higher mean expected gains and should be prefered.